# How to access different levels of a nested graphql response using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a graphql response that looks like this:

```js
{
    ethereum: {
        address: [{
            address: "0x980c55e501d2fad60b5702e2fd88232137e12145",
            balances: [{
                currency: {
                    address: "0x2a9718deff471f3bb91fa0eceab14154f150a385",
                    name: "ElonGate"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0xad90c05bc51672eedfee36e58b3ff1a78bbc146d",
                    name: "XSPACE"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0x33a3d962955a3862c8093d1273344719f03ca17c",
                    name: "SporeFinance"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0x85102c0062aa918cb9e26d94a284aafca602df13",
                    name: "Avalon Protocol"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0x07af67b392b7a202fad8e0fbc64c34f33102165b",
                    name: "Aquagoat"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0x31045e7023e6c388f9447e632a3f9eaff90393fa",
                    name: "Safe Token"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "-",
                    name: "Binance Smart Chain Native Token"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0x2222227e22102fe3322098e4cbfe18cfebd57c95",
                    name: "Alien Worlds Trilium"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0xdf6d9fc61bd8163b59d6381ec93ae1d3a4d95bb2",
                    name: "BlimpsRock"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0x2e291e1c9f85a86d0c58ae15621aac005a8b2ead",
                    name: "Zeppelin.dao"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0x6b51231c43b1604815313801db5e9e614914d6e4",
                    name: "SafeGalaxy"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0x8076c74c5e3f5852037f31ff0093eeb8c8add8d3",
                    name: "SafeMoon"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0xdbaaa36b347d56b77ce0e36f050fceebbf9fbc38",
                    name: "SavePlanetEarth"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0x3ad9594151886ce8538c1ff615efa2385a8c3a88",
                    name: "SafeMars"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0xf7844cb890f4c339c497aeab599abdc3c874b67a",
                    name: "NFTArt.Finance"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0xa57ac35ce91ee92caefaa8dc04140c8e232c2e50",
                    name: "Pitbull"
                }
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

I need to get access to all of the **address** fields under currency.

Using this:

```js
var x = body.data.ethereum.address[0].balances
```

I can get it down to the currency level:

```js
[{
    currency: {
        address: "0x2a9718deff471f3bb91fa0eceab14154f150a385",
        name: "ElonGate"
    }
}, {
    currency: {
        address: "0xad90c05bc51672eedfee36e58b3ff1a78bbc146d",
        name: "XSPACE"
    }
}, {
    currency: {
        address: "0x33a3d962955a3862c8093d1273344719f03ca17c",
        name: "SporeFinance"
    }
}, {
    currency: {
        address: "0x85102c0062aa918cb9e26d94a284aafca602df13",
        name: "Avalon Protocol"
    }
}, {
    currency: {
        address: "0x07af67b392b7a202fad8e0fbc64c34f33102165b",
        name: "Aquagoat"
    }
}, {
    currency: {
        address: "0x31045e7023e6c388f9447e632a3f9eaff90393fa",
        name: "Safe Token"
    }
}, {
    currency: {
        address: "-",
        name: "Binance Smart Chain Native Token"
    }
}, {
    currency: {
        address: "0x2222227e22102fe3322098e4cbfe18cfebd57c95",
        name: "Alien Worlds Trilium"
    }
}, {
    currency: {
        address: "0xdf6d9fc61bd8163b59d6381ec93ae1d3a4d95bb2",
        name: "BlimpsRock"
    }
}, {
    currency: {
        address: "0x2e291e1c9f85a86d0c58ae15621aac005a8b2ead",
        name: "Zeppelin.dao"
    }
}, {
    currency: {
        address: "0x6b51231c43b1604815313801db5e9e614914d6e4",
        name: "SafeGalaxy"
    }
}, {
    currency: {
        address: "0x8076c74c5e3f5852037f31ff0093eeb8c8add8d3",
        name: "SafeMoon"
    }
}, {
    currency: {
        address: "0xdbaaa36b347d56b77ce0e36f050fceebbf9fbc38",
        name: "SavePlanetEarth"
    }
}, {
    currency: {
        address: "0x3ad9594151886ce8538c1ff615efa2385a8c3a88",
        name: "SafeMars"
    }
}, {
    currency: {
        address: "0xf7844cb890f4c339c497aeab599abdc3c874b67a",
        name: "NFTArt.Finance"
    }
}, {
    currency: {
        address: "0xa57ac35ce91ee92caefaa8dc04140c8e232c2e50",
        name: "Pitbull"
    }
}]
```

But from here I can't access all of the address fields. I can access the first address by using:

`body.data.ethereum.address[0].balances[0].currency.address`

But ideally I need to get all address fields.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `body.data.ethereum.address[0].balances` is an array of objects `body.data.ethereum.address[0].balances[0].currency.address` is only going to access the very first of those objects.

You could use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get all addresses:

```js
const input = {
    ethereum: {
        address: [{
            address: "0x980c55e501d2fad60b5702e2fd88232137e12145",
            balances: [{
                currency: {
                    address: "0x2a9718deff471f3bb91fa0eceab14154f150a385",
                    name: "ElonGate"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0xad90c05bc51672eedfee36e58b3ff1a78bbc146d",
                    name: "XSPACE"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0x33a3d962955a3862c8093d1273344719f03ca17c",
                    name: "SporeFinance"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0x85102c0062aa918cb9e26d94a284aafca602df13",
                    name: "Avalon Protocol"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0x07af67b392b7a202fad8e0fbc64c34f33102165b",
                    name: "Aquagoat"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0x31045e7023e6c388f9447e632a3f9eaff90393fa",
                    name: "Safe Token"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "-",
                    name: "Binance Smart Chain Native Token"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0x2222227e22102fe3322098e4cbfe18cfebd57c95",
                    name: "Alien Worlds Trilium"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0xdf6d9fc61bd8163b59d6381ec93ae1d3a4d95bb2",
                    name: "BlimpsRock"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0x2e291e1c9f85a86d0c58ae15621aac005a8b2ead",
                    name: "Zeppelin.dao"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0x6b51231c43b1604815313801db5e9e614914d6e4",
                    name: "SafeGalaxy"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0x8076c74c5e3f5852037f31ff0093eeb8c8add8d3",
                    name: "SafeMoon"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0xdbaaa36b347d56b77ce0e36f050fceebbf9fbc38",
                    name: "SavePlanetEarth"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0x3ad9594151886ce8538c1ff615efa2385a8c3a88",
                    name: "SafeMars"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0xf7844cb890f4c339c497aeab599abdc3c874b67a",
                    name: "NFTArt.Finance"
                }
            }, {
                currency: {
                    address: "0xa57ac35ce91ee92caefaa8dc04140c8e232c2e50",
                    name: "Pitbull"
                }
            }]
        }]
    }
};

const addresses = input.ethereum.address[0].balances.map(x => x.currency.address);

console.log(addresses);
```

Comment: Do you know how we could remove the commas "," from this response?

Comment: @RyanBentham I'm not sure what you mean. There are no commas in `addresses` but in the console output of that array. Maybe it's better to ask a separate question for this?

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't very clear, and I missed out a key bit of info.  I'm writing the response to a html list which is including the commas.  I'll ask a new question. Thanks